# Multiple TCP Socket Requests on PHP

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

Is it possible to accept multiple requests (parallel) by using a socket server made on PHP?
If possible, how ?

Comment: perhaps a little on what you hoped to achieve by doing this, my solicit a better quality answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal PHP script cannot receive multiple requests. But if you really plan on creating a socket server (started as cmdline php script), then yes it's possible.

Look into http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Server - it provides already some preparations for that. Specifically it uses the [`pcntl`](http://php.net/pcntl) functions to fork into multiple processes to work on separate TCP requests.

Another option would be http://nanoserv.si.kz/ which has a few more features.