# Prevent stream socket opened in parent to be closed by child fork

Tags: php, sockets, cryptography, signals, parent-child

I have a worker which spans new jobs with `pcntl_fork()`, I would like to reuse the same connection in each child without the need to reconnect every time in each child, the goal is to gain a huge performance boost.

1. In the parent I connect to a SMTP service, then fork off a child.
2. The first child successfully can use the SMTP stream and can send the message.
3. The socket is automatically closed when the child ends. I do not call any close function neither destructors, you can see in the attached repo example.
4. After this the parent nor the next child can use the opened socket anymore.

I want to prevent number 3. so that the next child can reuse the socket, without needing to reconnect again, as you know SMTP protocol is chatty and takes time to reconnect. The SMTP server could be sendmail/sendgrid/Gmail, I tried multiple providers and the problem is in my PHP and not the SMTP protocol.

I read that signals might causing the close of the stream. Is there a way I can prevent this.

what are my options?

I am using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), I removed the [close from destructor](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L588). I activated `SMTPKeepAlive` but didn't helped, as you can see in the attached repo example. If matters I am using PHP 5.4

**Update 1**

I added sample code into this public repo: https://github.com/pentium10/php_stream_socket_test and you can check the dispostable inbox at http://www.dispostable.com/inbox/test/

You can find the output and the SMTP response in the README file of the repo. I confirm that removing anything from the fork/child/exit call, the example works and sends multiple messages one after the other.

Comment: A socket isn't really closed until all the processes that have it open close it. Number 4 doesn't happen, the parent should still be able to use the socket.

Comment: Does the child send a `QUIT` command on the connection? That will cause the server to close the connection.

Comment: It doesn't send the QUIT command, I verified using sleep(), and the connection is closed when the child exits.

Comment: It's PHP. all resources are closed/cleaned up when the script exits. You cannot prevent this. PHP won't be aware that it's a forked copy and exempt any resources from that cleanup. Each script exists in its own little universe with no awareness of what's happening around it.

Comment: @MarcB There's no way for a process to close a descriptor in another process. The child process can close its descriptor, but if it's shared with the parent process the parent's copy will still be open.

Comment: I've found something extremely similar discussed here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692026/multi-threaded-socket-based-server-possible-in-php Just I don't know what would be the solution @Jacco recommends doing.

Comment: I don't know how you tell what's happening with `sleep()`. Use `tcpdump` or `Wireshark` to see what's sent.

Comment: just before calling exit() I have a sleep, and tcpdump shows no activity. But once reaches exit() it shows activity.

Comment: Could you please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Right now all we know is your narration that the socket is "closed" and then "can't be used."  But what does that mean?  SIGPIPE?  EBADF?  Error messages?  We don't know.  What you describe should be easy to demonstrate in a few dozen lines of code or less.

Comment: A socket is either closes expliclitly using `close()` or implicilty on or process exit. The receiption of a signal does not touch any socket at all.

Comment: @alk since the child is a new process, when calling exit() it closes. That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: As others pointed out: It's only the client-child's copy of the client-parent's socket that gets closed. Closing a client side socket does not close the server side socket. So the client-parent shall still be able to communicated with the server. Also see *Alain Tiemblo*'s answer on this.

Comment: @alk I am not running the server side socket, that's the SMTP server.

Comment: I understand this. All I wanted to point out was that signals might not be related to the issue you describe.

Comment: "*After this the parent nor the next child can use the socket.*" Which error(s) do you get? What behaviour do you exactly observe for the parent/next child?! What does the server-log tell you?

Comment: @alk I am not running the server. It's an SMTP server either at Gmail/Sendgrid/Mandrill. Simply the second child cannot connect.

Comment: @pilcrow I added the example code.

Comment: Did you try adding a delay (start testing with 1 sec, then increase by factor 2) before sending the 2nd mail (key word: "tarpitting" as  performed by (certain) mail servers as a defense to spammers)? Referring debugging: I'd run this against my own mail server, to learn what it does in the cases you observer.

Comment: @alk I tried, and no change. I can do a direct loop, with no sleep, and the mail server accepts the message, within the same connection. I tried just now with Sendgrid with thousands messages, and no fail. But using fork/child it fails.

Comment: "*I can do a direct loop ...*": Doing **one** `HELO` ... `STARTTLS`, followed by **multiple** `MAIL` ... `RSET`, as per your parent/child log?

Comment: @alk exactly, with RSET and multiple MAIL. I even have a graphite chart for you: http://screencast.com/t/bhfleAFogBu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigations in the code you given, it looks like your issue comes when you enable TLS.

If you disable the following line:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Your code will work as expected (as soon as your smtp server accept unsecure connections).

So this is definitely **not a socket nor a fork issue**, but probably **a TLS protocol violation**.

If you try to send a RSET verb (eg. calling `$mail->getSMTPInstance()->reset();` before your `email()` call), the error when sending the second mail is clearer:

```
2014-11-04 00:23:18 SMTP ERROR: RSET command failed:
2014-11-04 00:23:18 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
```

I am not a crypto expert so I can't get further. But I'm pretty sure that the resource used by [stream_socket_client](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) (and wrapped with [stream_socket_enable_crypto](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-enable-crypto.php)) stores some contextual information required to do the next TLS transaction. After sending an email from the first child, the resource's context is up to date on the child's memory, but not on the parent's one. So when you try to send another email using your old context, TLS breaks.

Comment: You are missing an exit() in child, after: `socket_close($sock) or err('close');`  to properly close a forked process, and not leave behind any.

Comment: I implemented your code, and I still have the issues. See my linked example in the repo.

Comment: @Pentium10: This is strong evidence that this a server related issue.

Comment: @alk see my comment addressed to you at the top.

Comment: You can find an interesting discussion of such a connection transfer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767529/openssl-how-to-accept-ssl-connection-in-one-process-and-reuse-the-same-ssl-cont

Comment: @AlainTiemblo thanks for figuring out it was with TLS. I removed it and it works super great.